# populate a table from another table row onclick using DOJO

Tags: dojo

I have a table which is in normal HTML table and not in DOJO. Now I need to have a feature, that when I click on a row, another table has to be populated with details related to that clicked row. I need to do it only on DOJO. I do not have any code for this, because it’s a start-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample how you can connect an onClickEvent to a TableRow. I'm using dojo 1.9

The HTML-Table:

```
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
   <th>Berlin</th>
   <th>Hamburg</th>
   <th>M&uuml;nchen</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td id="m1">Milj&ouml;h</td>
    <td id="m2">Kiez</td>
    <td id="m3">Bierdampf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Buletten</td>
    <td>Frikadellen</td>
    <td>Fleischpflanzerl</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="InertGridHere"> Here comes the DataGrid</div>
```

And the Javascript for the OnClick connection:

```
require(["dojo/dom","dijit/registry","dojo/on","dojo/json","dojo/domReady!"],function(dom,registry,on,JSON){

on(dom.byId("m1"),"click",function(){
     fillTable('M1');
});
on(dom.byId("m2"),"click",function(){
     fillTable('M2');
});
on(dom.byId("m3"),"click",function(){
     fillTable('M3');
});


function fillTable(Element){

    //programm your query for building the
    //Store for the DGrid
    alert(Element);
 }
});
```

Now you must just decide what u pass to the function that builds the Grid.
Here's the fiddle for the Example above : http://jsfiddle.net/uPfNR/2/

Here's a starter for you:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#dojox-grid-datagrid
and a Tutorial how to use a Grid:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/datagrid/

regards, Miriam

Comment: You can do it like this: Set a query and use a filter for this on the onClick Event. https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/example_Filtering_data.html